# Rails: How to post on my main facebook page through API?

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I have the following permissions:

`create_note, email, offline_access, photo_upload, publish_stream, read_stream, share_item, status_update, manage_notifications, read_friendlists, video_upload, user_relationships, user_status, user_photos`

I can do post on the user timeline (www.facebook.com/username) but I can't see how to post on the user's wall (www.facebook.com)

To post on the user timeline, I use a code something like:

if I need to attach an image to the post

`client.put_connections("me", "feed", attachments, attachments)`

and

if I don't need to attach an image to the post

`client.put_connections("me", "links", attachments, attachments)`

both are working nice, but none of them really publish the message on the wall (www.facebook.com as a logged in user)

So, I just wondering if it is a normal behaviour or am I just missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference between user timeline and user's wall post. Can you explain?

Comment: If I'm logged in and go to facebook.com and post some text, the post appears on my timeline (facebook.com/my_user_name). But if I do some post through my application, the post only appears on my friends feeds, doesn't appear on my feed, but appears on my timeline.

I want that when I post something using my application, I can see the post on my feeds page. Can you understand what I mean?

Comment: I can understand .. this is a problem. But in case when you share a photo using facebook login it will not appear on feed (you can see a notification not the photo you shared).

Comment: So, I can take this as a normal behaviour of the facebook api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same behavior I can see for other users those are sharing update from API. I think it's normal and we need not to worry about it.

As per me : We can't not say this is required because getting our own feed in 'News Feed' section is not beneficial at all.